# Flutter: Is there a widget which merely wraps another widget with a key?

Tags: flutter, widget

Is there any particular widget which only wraps an existing widget with the given key? So it should have only 2 arguments - key and child.

I know I can achieve this with many other widgets such as Container widget but just wondering if there's any particular one which is meant for this purpose.

Comment: it's `KeyedSubtree`

Comment: @pskink that answers it. If you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @pskink mentioned, [KeyedSubtree](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/KeyedSubtree-class.html) is the widget you're looking for.

Example:

```
KeyedSubtree(
  key: UniqueKey(), // Or any other Key implementation.
  child: YourWidget(),
)
```

Note: This post was answered in the comments by @pskink. This answer is just here to highlight the correct answer.